# Authentication scheme in asp.net framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a web service by using Asp.net Framework.
I'm struggling with jwt authentication.

I wonder if there is any **AuthenticationHandler** in ASP.NET Framework as ASP.Net core or not - where I can **get token** from request header, **validate** and **set to HttpContext**.

I want to authenticate every single request as header is available. 
In AuthorizeAttribute, I only **get the information** from **HttpContext.User** and validate the availability of account in my system without parsing token there.

Finally, my question is : **How can I write AuthenticationHandler to validate every API Request ?**

Thank you,

Comment: [Have you done any research?](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jwt%20authentication%20.net%20web%20service) Are any of the linked articles useful? Narrow down your problem as this is to broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did already before asking this question. Thing I'm talking about is create my own authenticationhandler.

Comment: This question seems to ask something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095076/custom-authentication-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Not similar :| . I'm asking about ASP.NET Framework, not Core