# How to use pre-existing tables for Entity Framework and ASP.Net Core Identity

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to use authentication in an ASP.NET Core project using Angular. The problem is that we have a database full of tables that are already in use. In particular, we have a `User` table and a `UserTypes` table which is basically our 'Roles.' I would like to use IdentityServer since that seems to be the default option when creating a new project. I have used the following command in Package Manager Console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=-----;Database=MP_Administration;Persist Security Info=True;User id=sa; Password=------" 
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
         -OutputDir Models -Context MpContext -t User, UserType
```

It works fine but in my `Startup.cs` I'm struggling to make things work. I would like to do something like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<MpContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MPAdministrationDatabase")));

services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MpContext>();

services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<User, MpContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

But the Identity Server doesn't seem to like the `MpContext` (which implements `DbContext`) generated by the scaffolding command mentioned earlier. I've tried writing my own versions of `ApiAuthorizationDbContext` which would take the place of `DbContext`, as well as `KeyApiAuthorizationDbContext`, but I'm slowly starting to feel like I'm sinking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I could never find an answer to this question. I did, however, find an acceptable alternative. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49047358/1809219) was basically what I did. However, I used Jwt authentication as opposed to Cookie. Works great! I hope someone finds a good solution to the original problem though.