# .NET Core Authorize attribute with external JWT authentication microservice?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, asp.net-core, jwt, microservices

So I'm just having a bit of trouble getting my head round the .NET Core [Authorize] attribute.

I have an authentication service running (let's say `authapi.com`) which when provided with valid authentication details will return a JWT.  When this JWT is given back to it, it will validate the JWT and return a message indicating such.

So, I'm now building another WebAPI (let's say `genericapi.com`)which will require authorization for some of the actions/controllers.  The idea being, the JWT will be passed in the headers of the request to `genericapi` which then needs to pass those on to `authapi.com` to validate them.

I tried adding a Policy but it got convoluted really quick, and I had to write `[Authorize(Policy="TokenValid")]` on everything, when I'd rather just the default `[Authorize]` did this, since ALL authorization will have to hit `authapi`.

How would I go about getting that JWT from the header and passing it to the `authapi` as standard behaviour for `[Authorize]`?

Bear in mind: I don't want to do anything with the JWTs on `genericapi`, all authentication is to be handled by `authapi`.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to customize the default `JwtBearerAuthenticationMiddleware` providing to it a custom `ISecurityTokenValidator`. Your user identity will be automatically set by the middleware, and you may continue using the `Authorize` attribute inside MVC:

```
class MyTokenValidator : ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    public string AuthenticationScheme { get; }

    public MyTokenValidator(string authenticationScheme)
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = authenticationScheme;
    }

    public bool CanValidateToken => true;

    public int MaximumTokenSizeInBytes
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public bool CanReadToken(string securityToken) => true;

    public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
    {
        validatedToken = null;

        //your logic here
        var response = GetResponseFromMyAuthServer(securityToken);
        //assuming response will contain info about the user

        if(response == null || response.IsError)
            throw new SecurityTokenException("invalid");

        //create your identity by generating its claims
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, response.UserId),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, response.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, response.UserName),
        };

        return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationScheme));
    }
}
```

And in your startup class:

```
var options = new JwtBearerOptions();
options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MyTokenValidator(options.AuthenticationScheme));

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);

//the rest of your code here
app.UseMvc();
```

You may need to further refine this approach, but this way you can achieve what you need by delegating all the validation to the remote endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand you don't want to use `JwtBearerAuthentication` in `genericapi`. In this case you can write custom authentication middleware(send jwt to `authapi` and validate it, then set current user) for `genericapi`. Then just use `[Authorize]` attribute.

To write custom authentication middleware take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37415902/5426333

**However** if possible, i wouldn't go with your way. I would use `JwtBearerAuthentication` for `genericapi`. Then i would use `OnTokenValidated` event to handle other validations.

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
        {
            Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
            {
                OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    // send jwt to auth api
                    // validate it
                    if (!valid)
                    {
                        context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Actually you've pretty much nailed what I was after, I think I misinterpreted what JwtBearerAuthentication does.  I'll give it another run through now and see.