# Bypass Authorize Attribute in .Net Core for Release Version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a way to "bypass" authorization in asp.net core?  I noticed that the Authorize attribute no longer has a AuthorizeCore method with which you could use to make decisions on whether or not to proceed with auth.

Pre .net core you could do something like this:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    // no auth in debug mode please
    #if DEBUG
       return true;
    #endif

    return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
}
```

I hope I'm not missing something blatantly obvious but it would be nice to be able to skip the auth workflow in DEBUG if needed.  I just haven't been able to find it for .net core

Comment: You are not supposed to derive from `AuthorizeAttribute`. Look into policy based authorization. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html You can write requirements which have more than 1 handlers and use a different handler as fallback in case the first one doesn't authorize (unless the first one calls `context.Failed()`). Fallback example can be found here https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html#why-would-i-want-multiple-handlers-for-a-requirement

Comment: Thanks @Tseng that's good information.  It's frustrating however that it seems as though we lost the ability to **simply** turn auth on/off depending on whether or not your in DEBUG or RELEASE mode.  So am I correct in assuming that I can either wrap **all** my [Authorize] attributes around #if DEBUG directives **or** wire up some policy/requirements/handler to do it in one central place?   And how would that look?

Comment: Well, yea. But nothing prevents you from creating a base requirement class where all your other requirements derive from and add this check there

Comment: Added an example on how to use a base requirement handler

Comment: The solution here worked well for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40156927/5329320

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can create a base class for all your requirement handlers.

```
public abstract class RequirementHandlerBase<T> : AuthorizationHandler<T> where T : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected sealed override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, T requirement)
    {
#if DEBUG
        context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.FromResult(true);
#else
        return HandleAsync(context, requirement);
#endif
    }

    protected abstract Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, T requirement);
}
```

Then derive your requirement handlers from this base class.

```
public class AgeRequirementHandler : RequirementHandlerBase<AgeRequirement>
{
    protected override HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AgeRequirement requirement)
    {
        ... 
    }
}

public class AgeRequirement : IRequrement 
{
    public int MinimumAge { get; set; }
}
```

And then just register it.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Over18",
                      policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AgeRequirement { MinimumAge = 18 }));
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add an anonymous filter could do the trick, simple and easy.

```
   services.AddMvc(opts =>
   {
      opts.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
   });
```

Ref: https://www.illucit.com/asp-net/asp-net-core-2-0-disable-authentication-development-environment/

Comment: Easy solution  :)

Comment: v3 breaking change documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore#authorization-iallowanonymous-removed-from-authorizationfiltercontextfilters

Answer (score 5):

You can define your own handler that disables authorization:

```
public class DisableAuthorizationHandler<TRequirement> : AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement>
    where TRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and then register it:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    //...
#if DEBUG
    services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, DisableAuthorizationHandler<IAuthorizationRequirement>>();
#endif
    //...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For someone still needs to get the fake User object, the below solution can do the trick:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.User = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    }, "test"));
    await next.Invoke();
});

app.UseMvc();
```

The solution should just work if the **DefaultScheme** is "**Cookies**".

Comment: This is brilliant for debugging an API. If you put it between UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization you can conditionally add a fake user with any claims you like.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions coming to my mind.

**First** is to use fake `Authentication Middleware`. You can create a fake authentication middleware like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396709/simple-token-based-authentication-authorization-in-asp-net-core-for-mongodb-data). And your `Startup.cs` should be something like this(you should take care of fake services):

```
private IHostingEnvironment _env;

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  _env = env;
  // other stuff
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // ...
  if (_env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    // dev stuff
    services.AddTransient<ISomeService, FakeSomeService>();
  }
  else
  {
    // production stuff
    services.AddTransient<ISomeService, SomeService>();
  }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
         app.UseFakeAuthentication();
     }
     else
     {
         app.UseRealAuthentication();
     }
}
```

**Second** is to use more than one handlers(as @Tseng said). In this case i would write something like this:

```
private IHostingEnvironment _env;

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
  _env = env;
  // other stuff
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // ...
  if (_env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    // dev stuff
     services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, FakeAuthorizationHandler>();
  }
  else
  {
    // production stuff
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RealAuthorizationHandler>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding off of John_J's answer:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

#if DEBUG
        services.AddMvc(opts =>
        {
            opts.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
        });
#else
        services.AddMvc();
#endif
    }
```