# ASP.NET Core with optional authentication/authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to build an ASP.NET Core based WebApi for accessing data from a database. This WebApi could be used in two ways, either as a public WebApi which would need authentication or as a private backend service for a web application. In the latter case there would be no need for authentication since only authenticated users can access the web application and both web application and WebApi will run on the same computer, the WebApi will be hidden to the outside.

Since we need authentication for the first scenario, I will have all public APIs tagged with the Authorize attribute. But for the private scenario I would like to bypass any authentication.

Is there any way I could make authentication optional depending on some flag in the configuration?

**Update**

speaking of two usage scenarios I mean two completely separate installations! Each one has its own configuration file. The decision whether authentication is needed is to made per installation not per request in a single installation! My goal is to have just one code base and a switch in the configuration.

Comment: Could the downvoter please comment about what I did wrong with asking this or the way I asked it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bypass authentication, how do you distinguish internal or public requests for api? This causes security bug. So you shouldn't bypass authentication.

If you use openidconnect authentication in mvc application then you can set `SaveTokens=true`. It enables you to store access token in cookie. When you call api in mvc action you can send this `access_token` to api.

Another way using two different authentication middleware, one for internal another for public access(This is hard to implement).

I would go with first approach.

**Update**

To achieve your goal, a tricky way is coming to my mind but i am not sure it is good way:

Create a filter provider:

```
public class EncFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public int Order
    {
        get
        {
            return -1500;
        }
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
        // remove authorize filters
        var authFilters = context.Results.Where(x => 
           x.Descriptor.Filter.GetType() == typeof(AuthorizeFilter)).ToList();
        foreach(var f in authFilters)
            context.Results.Remove(f);
    }
}
```

Then register it conditionally based on config value

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      if(config["servermode"] = "internal")
      {
          services.AddScoped<IFilterProvider, EncFilterProvider>();
      }
   }
```

Comment: I don't want to distinguish internal or public requests at runtime for each request! I thought that it may be possible to bypass authentication for my private instance by configuration. For example reading out a value from appsettings.json that tells me whether authentication should be used. I probably cannot switch on/off the Authorize attribute by configuration. Maybe I could avoid adding the authorization middleware at startup depending on my configuration. Implementing my own middleware would certainly solve the problem but, as you say, probably too hard to implement for me.

Comment: Suppose you bypass authentication for internal requests anyway(may be ip control or signature request). In this case don't you need to get current user in api action?

Comment: No, for the private instance of my WebApi there would be only one client and that is my web application which is trusted so it has access to everything and in the WebApi there are no user settings that I would have to identify, it's only about access control. Actually the web application handles authentication/authorization. See also my update in the question...

Comment: Finally i understood you correctly :) I updated my answer, it may be useful for you.

Comment: that looks very interesting! I will have to test it but the idea already seems just like what I expected.

Comment: I can confirm that this works with ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 and IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation 1.0.1 RC2.

Comment: What does the Order -1500 do?

Comment: @GlacialFlames To work before default filter provider.

Comment: @ademcaglin when I am implementing the code that you suggested, I get no controller/action which have filters on them in the filterProviderContext.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to authenticate both applications: web application and the Web API one. You will have everything secured.
For skipping an authentication that is not a good idea. Simply create an user for your web application (in the Web API application) which will be used to authenticate when getting data from the Web API.

Comment: The thing is that I plan to use IdentityServer as the external token provider. For then internal instance of my WebApi that would mean there is a round-trip to the IdentityServer on every request although the trusted web application is the only client that can ever connect to this WebApi instance.