# IdentityServer - How to bypass authorization for simple debug

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I have several .NET core API and I use IdentityServer 4 as a seperate service for authentication.

The problem is that in "debug" I also wish to run my API without authentication (without launching the IdentityServer).

So, I try to bypass it... I have try several solutions, but none work:
 - With a AuthorizationHandler: [Bypass Authorize Attribute in .Net Core for Release Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706125/bypass-authorize-attribute-in-net-core-for-release-version)
 - With a Middleware : [Simple token based authentication/authorization in asp.net core for Mongodb datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396709/simple-token-based-authentication-authorization-in-asp-net-core-for-mongodb-data)
 - With a filter : [ASP.NET Core with optional authentication/authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142715/asp-net-core-with-optional-authentication-authorization/40156927#40156927)
 - With AllowAnonymousFilter : [Bypass Authorize Attribute in .Net Core for Release Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706125/bypass-authorize-attribute-in-net-core-for-release-version)

But no way, none of theses solutions work, I still got a "401 Undocumented Error: Unauthorized" !

Here is some parts of my code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // JSON - setup serialization
    services.AddControllers().
        AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(new TargetSpot.Core.Json.SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()));
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
        });

    // Force lowercase naming
    services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // Setup the connection to the IdentityServer to request a token to access our API
    services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("APISettings")["AuthorityURL"];
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ApiName = Configuration.GetSection("APISettings")["APIName"];
    });

    // Add swagger
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        //options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "HTTP API",
            Version = "v1",
            Description = "The Service HTTP API",
            TermsOfService = new Uri("http://www.myurl.com/tos")
        });

        // XML Documentation
        var xmlFile = $"{System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();            
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseSwagger().UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Winamp API v1");
    });
}
```

Comment: have you tried to just remove  `[Authorize]` attribute on your api controller?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.
`AllowAnonymousFilter` works in ASP.NET Core 2.2 but not in ASP.NET Core 3.x.
After day of investigation I have found out that switching from `UseEndpoints` to `UseMvc` solved it and I can now disable authentication without commenting out `[Authorize]` attributes.

It seems that `UseEndpoints` does not use filter when registered by `AddMvc` but how to correctly register it when using `UseEndpoints` I do not know.

My solution
`Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc(o =>
{
    o.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    o.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
});
```

`Startup.Configure`:

```
// anonymous filter works with UseMvc but not with UseEndpoints
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

//app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
//{
//    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
//        name: "default",
//        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
//});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this link: https://docs.identityserver.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/. Obviously I had to remove the Authorize attributes I added manually in my controllers.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // Allowing Anonymous access to all controllers but only in Local environment
    if (env.IsEnvironment(Constants.ApplicationConstants.LocalEnvironment))
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    else
        endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
});
```