# Bypass authorization and allow admins access to everything in .NET Core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization

I want to allow a user with the role "Admin" to access every resource implicitly.

Consider this example :

```
[Authorize(Role = "BusinessOwner")]
public class UpdateModel : PageModel
{
    public ActionResult OnPost()
    {
    }
}
```

The role "Admin" has to be set explicitly. Adding all roles to the admin user is not an option because roles can (read will) change over time.

```
[Authorize(Role = "Admin, BusinessOwner")]
public class UpdateModel : PageModel
{
    public ActionResult OnPost()
    {
    }
}
```

It's not recommended to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` anymore so what's the best practice to bypass the authorization check and allow admins access in .NET Core 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took heavy inspiration from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38773345/3878764.

If the admin has access to everything, then you don't need to explicitly check this authorization logic on EVERY action. You would only need to check it on actions that are already restricted - and the admin role would bypass the restriction.

So for example, if you used policy-based authorization, you could write a Base AuthorizationHandler that would short-circuit the logic if the admin role was found.

```
public abstract class RequirementHandlerBase<T> : AuthorizationHandler<T> where T : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected sealed override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, T requirement)
    {            
        //if admin then short-circuit with success
        if (context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);    
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        return HandleAsync(context, requirement);
    }

    protected abstract Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, T requirement);
}
```

Have ALL your Handlers derive from the base:

```
public class AgeRequirementHandler : RequirementHandlerBase<AgeRequirement>
{
    protected override HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AgeRequirement requirement)
    {
        ... 
    }
}

public class AgeRequirement : IRequrement 
{
    public int MinimumAge { get; set; }
}
```

And just register like normal:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Over18",
                      policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AgeRequirement { MinimumAge = 18 }));
});
```

Also, this documentation on Policy-based Role checks might be useful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2#policy-based-role-checks

Answer (score 1):

Try policy-based authorization. You can find an example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2 It is quite flexible with whichever role and other property combination you want.

Once you create the policy, you can apply it as a global filter.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(o =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireRole("Admin")
            .Build();
        o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
}
```

Comment: How to use policies and not write `[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole")]` everywhere?

Comment: @maxbeaudoin I have added code sample to may answer. That should do it.

Comment: From the look of it, it looks like you're "Admin" or you're nothing.

Comment: In that case, you need to do it the long way as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56658483/1588156