# Conditionally use custom middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created my custom authentication middleware in asp. net core project, and registered it as shown below:

```
public class MyAuthenticationMidleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ConnectAuthenticationMidleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!UserIsAuthenticated())
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return;
        }
        ...
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

public static class MyAuthenticationMidlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyAuthenticationMidleware>();
    }
}
```

In Startup:

```
    public void Configure(...)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMyAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

This works correctly - authentication middleware is run for each request. If user is not authenticated, 401 is returned. Otherwise specific mvc action is invoked.

What I tried to do was to prevent the authentication middleware from running for some specific actions. I used `MapWhen` method to create another extension method and used it as follows:

```
public static class MyAuthenticationMidlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyAuthenticationMidleware>();
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyAuthenticationWhen(this IApplicationBuilder builder, Func<HttpContext, bool> predicate)
    {
        return builder.MapWhen(predicate, applicationBuilder => applicationBuilder.UseMyAuthentication());
    }
}

public void Configure(...)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMyAuthenticationWhen(context => context.Request.Path != "xyz");
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected. The middleware is invoked only when path is different than "xyz", but it seems that it short-circuts the whole chain - no mvc specific actions or filters are invoked.

Probably my understanding of `MapWhen` is incorrect. Is there any way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapWhen` is used to seperate middleware pipeline. If you want to use mvc for branced pipeline you need to add separetely. So you should use `.UseMvc();` in extension method like below:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyAuthenticationWhen(this IApplicationBuilder builder, Func<HttpContext, bool> predicate)
{
    return builder.MapWhen(predicate, applicationBuilder =>
    { 
        applicationBuilder.UseMyAuthentication();
        applicationBuilder.UseMvc();
    });
}
```

**However** i wouldn't go with your way. For authentication middleware i would implement my own middleware like [Simple token based authentication/authorization in asp.net core for Mongodb datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396709/simple-token-based-authentication-authorization-in-asp-net-core-for-mongodb-data/37415902#37415902) and use `Authorize` attribute for authorization mvc actions.

Answer (score 7):

`MapWhen` creates a new pipeline branch when the supplied predicate is true, and that branch does *not* rejoin with the main branch where you have `UseMvc()`.

You can change your extension method to use `UseWhen` instead of `MapWhen`. `UseWhen` [rejoins with the main pipeline](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/issues/137#issuecomment-141702228) so that your `UseMvc()` will still get called.

> Note: While the above link references aspnet-contrib, the `UseWhen` extension method is now part of [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/UseWhenExtensions.cs).

**This allows you to keep `UseMvc()` explicit in your `Configure` method instead of hidden away in your authentication extension method, where it really has no business being.**